# Delphi Calling .Clear on a TObjectList<T> calls destructor on contained objects

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I have a project where i have a model class containing a TObjectList. The lists holds a set of calculations objects when i empty out the list using the clear function i then do some operations on the objects afterwards (i have the objects referenced to other class fields). But when i call the clear function i can see using the debugger that the Destroy function is called on the objects in the list thereby creating an access violation.

From the delphi documentation it states that the Clear function should not try to free the objects, but it appears as if it actually does call the destroy/destructure.

Comment: Have you looked into TObjectList.OwnsObjects property?  It it true by default.

Answer (score 6):

> when i call the clear function i can see using the debugger that the Destroy function is called on the objects in the list

That is, literally, the single most defining feature of `TObjectList` over, say, a `TList`.  `TObjectList` has an `OwnsObjects` property, which is true by default. Per the documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList

> Use `TObjectList` to store and maintain a list of objects. `TObjectList` provides properties and methods to add, delete, rearrange, locate, access, and sort objects. If the `OwnsObjects` property is set to true (the default), `TObjectList` controls the memory of its objects, freeing an object when its index is reassigned; **when it is removed from the list with the `Delete`, `Remove`, or `Clear` method**; or when the `TObjectList` instance is itself destroyed.

So, if you need to continue accessing objects after removing them from the list, then either:

- set `OwnsObjects` to false.
- use the [`TObjectList.Extract()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList.Extract) method to remove individual objects without freeing them.
- don't use a container that destroys objects to begin with.

> From the delphi documentation it states that the Clear function should not try to free the objects, but it appears as if it actually does call the destroy/destructure.

I don't know what documentation you are reading, but the above quote is taken from `TObjectList`'s documentation, and it clearly says the opposite of what you claim.